# Calling a function automatically in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile-6

I would like to call a function automatically lets say every 2 secs.

Is this possible with .NET, and if so can you please paste some code?
This will be used in Windows Mobile 6 SDK

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saba8ksx.aspx):

> Provides a mechanism for executing a method at specified intervals.
>
> Platforms: [...],  .NET Compact Framework

You can find an example in the linked MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `System.Threading.Timer`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) is what you need to use.